# Loop within a function in R

Tags: r, function, loops, if-statement

I want to create a function that holds an ifelse statement like follows:

```
ArrearsL1M<-function(input1, input2, input3, input4){
  output=0
  output=ifelse((df[[input1]] %in% c(1,2,3,4,5)),1,
                ifelse((df[[input2]] %in% c(1,2,3,4,5)),1,
                       ifelse((df[[input3]] %in% c(1,2,3,4,5)),1,
                              ifelse((df[[input4]] %in% c(1,2,3,4,5)), 1, 0))))
  return(output)
```

Then I'd have this:

```
df$Arrears_L1M<-ArrearsL1M("col_201823","col_201822","col_201821","col_201820")
```

Here is an example of the data:

```
  col_201823 col_201822 col_201821 col_201820 col_201819 col_201818 col_201817 col_201816 col_201815
1         99          5          4          2         99         99         99         99         99
2          3          0          3          2          3          3          3          3          3
3          2          2          2          2          2          2          2          2          2
4          0          0          0          1          0          0          0          0          0
5         99         99          5         99         99         99         99         99         99
6          2          1          4         99          2          2          2          2          2
7          1          1         99         99          1          1          1          1          1
```

So the code will check the previous 4 weeks of data starting with the most recent (i.e. 2018 week 23, week 22, week 21 and week 20)

The starting week can change and I want to make this work so that the I enter the first week and it runs the function for the past 4 weeks. **I only want to enter the first week, so only one input.** So if I enter col_201820 I will get the answer for weeks col_201820, col_201819, col_201818 and col_201817.

I'll want to run this for 52 weeks of data (i.e. a year ) at some point so I'm trying to make it easier to change if the starting week changes. **It also needs to go to 201752, 201751, 201750,if the starting week is 201801.**

I'm not sure where to start with this so can't show you anything I've already tried.

** Code for reproducible example

```
col_201823<-c(99,3,2,0,99,2,1)
col_201822<-c(5,0,2,0,99,1,1)
col_201821<-c(4,3,2,0,5,4,99)
col_201820<-c(2,2,2,1,99,99,99)
col_201819<-c(99,3,2,0,99,2,1)
col_201818<-c(99,3,2,0,99,2,1)
col_201817<-c(99,3,2,0,99,2,1)
col_201816<-c(99,3,2,0,99,2,1)
col_201815<-c(99,3,2,0,99,2,1)

test<-as.data.frame(cbind(col_201823,col_201822,col_201821,col_201820,col_201819,col_201818,col_201817,col_201816,col_201815))
```

Comment: What can't you use "case_when" function?

Comment: @Franky what do you mean? Where do you recommend using case_when?

Comment: You should study `help("|")`.

Comment: Also, you should reshape your data to long format. If you need more help, provide a reproducible example.

Comment: @Roland My manager has specifically asked i don't us "OR" (i.e "|") otherwise I would've. I've added in the example of the data.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I guess you want to figure out how to create a vector of weeks from a starting week. For instance

```
weeks_from_start <- function(x) {
    week <- as.integer(substring(x, nchar(x) - 1))
    rest <- substring(x, 1, nchar(x) - 2)
    paste0(rest, seq(week, by = -1, length.out=4))
}
```

so

```
> weeks_from_start("col_201823")
[1] "col_201823" "col_201822" "col_201821" "col_201820"
```

Use this at the top of your `ArrearsL1M()` function. I would implement this as

```
ArrearsL1M <- function(df, last_week) {
    weeks <- weeks_from_start(last_week)
    m <- as.matrix(df[, weeks])
    m[] <- m %in% 1:5               # test all elements in 1 call; format as matrix
    rowSums(m) != 0
}
```

For more complicated parsing, revise `weeks_from_start()` as

```
week0 <- as.integer(substring(x, nchar(x) - 1))
year0 <- as.integer(substring(x, 5, 8))

week0 <- seq(week0, by = -1, length.out = 4)
week <- (week0 - 1) %% 52 + 1
year <- year0 - cumsum(week0 == 0)
sprintf("col_%4d%.2d", year, week)
```

Probably this is approaching a 'hack', e.g., do all years have 52 weeks? For a year beginning on, say, Tuesday, is week 1 Tues - Sunday, week 52 of the previous year just Monday? Time to rethink how this data is represented...

Comment: Thanks for this, is there a way so if the first week is 201801 that it then goes to 201752?

Comment: I'm getting the error: Error in weeks_from_start(last_week) : object 'year' not found

Answer (score 0):

```
ArrearsL1M <- function(input1, input2, input3, input4){

  cols <- c(input1, input2, input3, input4)

  output <- as.numeric(apply(apply(df[, cols], 2, function(x) x %in% 1:5), 1, any))

  return(output)

}
```

With 1 imput:

```
ArrearsL1M <- function(cols){

  output <- as.numeric(apply(apply(df[, cols], 2, function(x) x %in% 1:5), 1, any))

  return(output)

}
```

Comment: This would mean that I still have to enter 4 inputs, I only want to enter 1 input.

Comment: You can reemplace the 4 input for a vector with the columns names (cols).